# How to re-open a status-declined feature-request?

Tags: discussion, meta

How can one request reconsideration of a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) after a certain period of time, let us say after one year?

Comment: No complex mechanism for this - just edit the question or add a new answer with some brilliant new idea how to implement it then you can @otify the moderator who declined asking to reconsider.

Comment: you can also place a bounty

Comment: Before you do request reconsideration, though, make sure one of the following is true: (1) you have an argument not previously made, or (2) circumstances have changed since then. It's very, very rare for anything to happen on the request if the only thing that's changed is that a year has elapsed.

Comment: Bribery... ​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Lix Or blackmail, cheaper and just as effective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need a good reason for doing so:

- The decline reason is no longer valid
- You have a compelling counter-argument against the decline reason.

Either way, you can edit the post/add an answer explaining whichever of the above two points is applicable.

Additionally, you may go into the post history, find the declining mod, and @notify them (you can @notify anyone in the post history), asking for removal of the tag. You can alternatively flag, though I personally prefer the previous option.