# Now that duplicate means "has an answer somewhere else," OP should be able to close own question as duplicate unilaterally

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, accepted-answer, duplicate-questions

(As of before I made the title twice as long but more specific - you should read my function names!) my question is a duplicate of

- [Closing my own question as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68629/closing-my-own-question-as-a-duplicate) (Oct 2010)
- [Allow question askers to close their own questions unilaterally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/allow-question-askers-to-close-their-own-questions-unilaterally) (July 2009)

However our business logic has changed so much since then and since I find the logic in the original questions obsolete I'm re-raising this.  As I have argued all over the place and there is some consensus on, **duplicates are much more like valid questions that *happen* to be answered somewhere else than they are like close-candidate questions.**  I'm putting this in bold since [it is okay to re-open feature requests if there is a reason things have changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89029/183887) (and also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134438/183887)), and our [current most official stance on duplicates being warmly received](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) comes from November 2010, more recent than either of the questions above.  The reasoning:

- The OP can accept an answer unilaterally.  Shouldn't the OP be able to unilaterally accept an answer on a linked question, viz., close as duplicate?
- If the question turns out to be a duplicate the OP has no way to indicate the question is resolved until at least 5 users have participated.  Those 5 users should *not* have had to drill into the question to figure this out, much like accepting an answer.
- In general all the reasons [accepting answers is important](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163740/183887), apply perfectly well here.

Comment: Yes - I would like to be able to do this with my own questions - especially here on Meta.

Comment: what if community disagrees with OP and decides to reopen the question they closed (5 reopen votes or 1 from moderator)? Would you expect OP to be allowed to unilaterally re-close it again?

Comment: @gnat good point.  don't allow.  exactly analogous to "what if the community disagrees with the accepted answer?"

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I think that's a valid dupe, but it's...  kind of long.

Comment: You don't need to read the entire thing @djechlin, everything you mention is covered in the first 5 sentences, all nicely spaced.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards okay fine.  Voting to close my own question as dupe.  Before someone points out the irony, I'd like to argue that this in fact, not ironic.

Comment: Of course it's not ironic, that's the point of our requests :-). Have an upvote because I agree with you!