# What is the process of a feature-request?

Tags: discussion, support

I wander around looking for information about how are feature-requests processed.

I came across [one *funny*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2728178) suggested edit then I went to Meta to research how to deal with it and what to do about the it. I usually come here when I am unsure about the use of granted privileges.

I've spent some time reading other users complains about the anonymous suggested edits.

The below question was asked over 2 years ago and its status is declined.

- [Prevent suggested edits coming from anonymous
  users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83457/prevent-suggested-edits-coming-from-anonymous-users)

What about the other 2 feature-requests (last and this year) which both seem to receive some upvotes and *yet* have not been declined.

- [Can we do more to warn anonymous users away from invalid edit
  suggestions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174409/can-we-do-more-to-warn-anonymous-users-away-from-invalid-edit-suggestions)
- [Lots of vandalism by anonymous edit
  suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140935/lots-of-vandalism-by-anonymous-edit-suggestions)

I have a few questions regarding the feature-request process:

[image: present time]

1. What time frame does the **present time**(*from the picture*)
   represent ?
2. How long do we have to wait before posting another feature-request
   and not be marked as a duplicate?
3. Is there amount of votes required in order for a feature-request to
   be accepted?

Comment: Related: [Why don't all bugs and feature-requests have moderator status tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60505), [How to re-open a status-declined feature-request?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134431), [Can we re-request features that were declined a sufficient while ago?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89026) (You ask muliple questions, so there are multiple duplicates...)

Comment: @CodyGray sorry but I cant see how to first one is related. The second and third link is related so thanks for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Until the circumstances of and/or justification for the denial of the feature request no longer apply
2. Same as the above
3. Nope! If they like it, they'll add it. If not, they won't. Community approval is only one factor of consideration.

In other words, they won't reconsider until the rationale for denial does not apply. Until this time, duplicate requests (which will generate duplicate answers) will be marked as such.

Votes are important, but are hardly everything.

Only some feature requests get status tags. They only typically add them if there's a canonical reason for denial, and only if they feel like it. If you'd like one to get one, flag for moderator attention.

Comment: And it's key that if you're re-posting the feature that you *explain* why the reason for denial no longer applies.

Comment: so the main factor remains as owners. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Servy good point

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange is a corporation, so ultimately decisions on implementing features rest with the owners and employees of the corporation, regardless of community support or approval.  The "present-time" timeframe doesn't really mean anything specific and can be a short or a long as it needs to be.

This question is a perfect example:
[Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

It was an extremely popular feature, but was marked as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) for a very long time (about 3.5 years).  It is also infamous for having the single most (undeleted) downvoted answer in the history of Meta Stack Overflow.  However, it was decided a short time ago to implement and the feature was added in the last few weeks.